# Come join our Weekly Community Anime Watch Event!~☆

Tags: discussion, events, chat

In order to help bring together new and veteran users of our site to different genres and series of anime, out community is holding a weekly social event in our [Review and Recommendations](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7576/recommendations-and-reviews) chatroom on Saturday.

Any and all users are welcome to join. A minimum of 20 rep is required to access the chatroom, you are encouraged to participate in our main Stack Exchange site, but it is not mandatory.  Any new users with less than 20 rep may ask a moderator for an invite to the room for this event via the Community's [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/AnimeAndMangaQA) or [Google+](https://plus.google.com/b/111061084179563499110/111061084179563499110/posts) Page.

The format of the event will be simple, the next event starts on **Sept. 14th, 2013 @ 1700 UTC (1pm EDT)**. Users interested in attending should watch the mentioned episode for some casual discussion of the various aspects of the episode or series, e.g. what you liked/didn't like, any references you noticed, trivia, or ask any questions you may have about the episode or series.

The session is expected to last about an hour. Click [here to view and register](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/7576/recommendations-and-reviews?tab=schedule) yourself!

For this week will be a **free topic** session. Come discuss whatever series you'd like.

If you have any issues feel free to join us in our [general chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-and-manga) and well try to help you as best we can. At the end of our sessions, we will be choosing the next series to watch.

Feel free to post your nominations as an answer to this question. Any TV series, OVA, or movies are alright. Newer and non-mainstream series are especially welcome, as they give new anime viewers a fresher perspective on the industry. Classic anime are welcome as well as long as they can be easily accessible by your average user.

Please use this template for your nominations:

> **Series Name**
>
> **Synopsis:** (Brief non-spoilery synopsis of the series. MAL, ANN, TVTropes, Wikipedia quotes are fine)
>
> **Reason:** (Your reason to choose this series)

Answer (score 6):

I think one of the more interesting shows so far this season has been **[Eccentric Family](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15205)** (*Uchōten Kazoku*)

**Synopsis**: In a time in Kyoto that's populated by humans, shapeshifting tanuki, and flying tengu, the head of the Shimogamo tanuki family, Souichirou, who has been the head of the tanuki community in Kyoto, has been eaten by a group of humans called the "Friday Club". With Shimogamo family now in decline, the story follows the son of Souichirou, Yasaburou, along with his mother, powerful older brother and timid younger brother (and another brother who decides he's better off as a frog). Now he's tasked with taking care of the old head of the tengu as he learns about his father and the tengu and human communities.

**Reason**: Really interesting characters and art style. Kind of a surreal setting where you're not sure how serious you're supposed to take everything, sometimes funny, sometimes serious.

The show is on Crunchyroll and is currently (as of 7/22/2013) on its third episode.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Kyousogiga](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=13434) would be a fun series to watch, especially with a TV series [coming this Fall Season (2013)](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-07-26/kyousogiga-anime-gets-tv-series-this-fall).

**Synopsis**:   The basic plot is pretty much ripped straight from that story: the main character, Koto, has somehow been sent to some crazy fantasy world and she is looking for a rabbit so that she can return home.  Everything else teeters on the edge of sort of making sense and being complete bullshit.  The story is also kind of clumsy in the way it sporadically skips from one scene to the next with almost no indication of who the people it’s focusing on are, but I guess that kind of goes along with the dreamlike world it’s set in.

**Reason**: The premise is a bit like *Alice in Wonderland*, but with the zany and outlandish styles of *Mononoke, Trapeze, Summer Wars, and FLCL*. The plot starts out a bit thin, but the action and character really draw you in, even when you don't know what's going on.

Check out the PV trailer and see for yourself [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=In4YoCWTKiM).

[image: Have taste here]

Answer (score 2):

**Children Who Chase Lost Voices** 
 
*Hoshi o Ou Kodomo (星を追う子ども) (lit. “Children Who Chase Stars”)*

**Synopsis:** The movie follows a young girl named Asuna who is living a standard life in small-town Japan after the death of her father as she discovers that there is a hidden world underground replete with fantastic creatures and a surprising history that may hold the key to resurrecting the dead.

**Reason:** Watching this movie will give any anime fan a lot of flashbacks to the heyday of Studio Ghibli fantasy adventures, but this movie really is much more than just a Ghibli clone.  *Children Who Chase Lost Voices* skews toward an older audience than other fantasy adventures dealing thematically with such subject matter as coping with loss and the purpose/inevitability of death while including the beautiful sweeping vistas and intricately detailed environments that Shinkai films are known for.  Certainly the best fantasy adventure anime to come out in a long while.

[image: Look who it is!]

[image: Just looking~]

[image: More scenery]